# how to call a function from module dependency (another module)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to create seperate module for pagination, because I will need it to reuse in different modules, but I don't know how to call a function from module dependency (another module)

Here is my main module:

```
var App = angular.module('search', ['pagination']);

App.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$pagination' function($scope, $pagination) {
    $scope.testFunction(); //function from pagination module controller
}])
```

Here is my pagination module:

```
var App = angular.module('pagination', []);

App.controller('PaginationController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.testFunction = function(){
        console.log("pagination module");
    }
}])
```

I get error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $paginationProvider <- $pagination
```

Comment: You haven't declared a service (provider) called `$pagination`. Where is that? You can't inject something that doesn't exist. Why are you creating a controller in the pagination module, only to be injected into another controller?

Comment: could you post some example how to do it?

Comment: There's plenty here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services . Instead of creating a controller in the pagination module, create a service/factory (and name it something else...Angular modules usually start with "$" and it's advised not to do it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share resources across two modules, declare a factory or a service.

Suppose you have a search module:

```
//you inject your pagination module here
var searchModule = angular.module('search', ['pagination']);

//and you ALSO need to inject your pagination's service into your controller
searchModule.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'paginationSvc' function($scope, paginationSvc) {
  //function from pagination module controller
  paginationSvc.testFunction();
}])
```

And your pagination module:

```
var pagination = angular.module('pagination', []);

//declare your pagination service here
pagination.factory('PaginationSvc', [function(){
 return {
   testFunction:testFunction
 };
 function testFunction(){
   console.log('This is from pagination module');
}
}])
```

Maybe a [little plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WADaC7MwvHQDcJHpoWOr?p=preview) will help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject a controller in a controller. Your `pagination` module need to declare a service or factory or provider wich will be be injected in your controller.

[See docs here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a pagination directive and insert that where you need it. You might get some good ideas from [this post](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs).